# Matrix manipulation with SAS/IML

Tags: sas

I am defining the basic matrix:

```
1         2         3         4
5         6         7         8
```

As follows:

```
PROC IML;
    RESET NOPRINT;
    matrix = {1 2 3 4, 5 6 7 8};
EXIT:
```

I'm looking to resample each row with replacement so we generate matrices like:

```
1         3         4         2
6         6         5         5
```

and

```
1         1         3         2
5         6         6         8
```

How can this be done?

Note that if you're not aligned with stats, to resample with replacement means if we have a set of data:

{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}

and wish to resample with replacement, we randomly pick 10 objects from the set to form a new 10-element set, and we're allowed to pick an element more than once (so the set {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1} is just as likely as any other.

Comment: Picky point, but your examples do not show "sampling each row with replacement," since that would select random rows in their entirety. From your example, I assume you want to resample the ELEMENTS of each row. That's what the answers assume as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not great with IML, but the most efficient approach would be to generate a new matrix that has in each row an integer in `1,...,k` where `k` is the number of variables (4 in your case). You can then use this matrix to reshuffle the elements of your existing matrix.

This approach is shown [in this blog post](http://blogs.sas.com/content/iml/2010/11/05/sampling-with-replacement/), except you'll have to modify it to work on your whole matrix -- in his code, the input is a row vector.

Comment: If you don't want to edit, you can call in a loop: do i=1 to nrow(matrix); s = SampleReplaceUni(matrix[i,], 1, ncol(m)); end;

Comment: Thanks @Rick. I was actually going to say in my post that your blog is a great source in general. Hadn't seen you here before.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to use the UNIFORM and INT functions to generate this, assuming that you are looking for relatively random integers between 0 and 9 in your result matrices.  Note that the UNIFORM function will use the first element in your matrix as the seed, so you will need to specify a different matrix to get a different sample.

```
PROC IML;
    RESET NOPRINT;
    matrix = {1 2 3 4, 5 6 7 8};

    matrix_uniform = uniform(matrix);
    matrix_int_1 = int(matrix_uniform*10);

    matrix_uniform = uniform(matrix_int_1);
    matrix_int_2 = int(matrix_uniform*10);

    print matrix_int_1;
    print matrix_int_2;
EXIT:
```

Comment: Thanks for the nice idea. However, the data I'm using isn't distributed quite as simply as it is in your solution.

Comment: Also I should mention that we don't strictly know how the data is distributed. Are you aware of any methods that just... resample?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure whether this is what you want. It's a simple program to select random elements from the original matrix. Replace x with any matrix you want.

```
proc iml;
x = {1 2 3 4, 5 6 7 8};
y= j(nrow(x),ncol(x),.);
    do i=1 to nrow(x);
      do j=1 to ncol(x);
        y[i,j]=x[int(1+(nrow(x)-1)*ranuni(0)),int(1+(ncol(x)-1)*ranuni(0))];
      end;
   end;
   print y ;
   quit;
```

Answer (score 0):

As @Itzy says, you can do this row-wise. A more efficient way is to generate all the indices (random numbers in 1:ncol(matrix)) at once and then directly index into the matrix to extract the values:

```
   u = j(nrow(x),ncol(x)); 
   call randgen(u, "Uniform"); /* u~U[0,1] */
   k = ceil( ncol(x)*u );  /* k ~ U{1,2,3,4} */
   y = shape(x[k], nrow(x), ncol(x)); /* suscript and reshape */
```

In addition to the blog post @Itzy mentioned, you might want to read "[How to generate random numbers in SAS](http://blogs.sas.com/content/iml/2011/08/24/how-to-generate-random-numbers-in-sas/)"